# Extract date from csv and place in the html header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a date to be extracted from the csv file. This is my code. It shows undefined in the header where it should display the date. Please help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

   <head>
    <title>Commtech Automation</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link href="green.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- bootstrap-progressbar -->
    <link href="bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- bootstrap-navbar -->
    <link href="bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jVectorMap -->
   <!-- <link href="css/maps/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css" rel="stylesheet"/> -->

    <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
   <link href="custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dc.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="introjs.css" />


        <!-- Displaying Date in navbar (header)-->

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Date:</a>
            <a id="mydate" class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>

       <script src="intro.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="crossfilter.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="dc.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="FileSaver.js"></script>
      <script src='bootstrap.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

     //var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y").parse; 

         <!--Getting the CSV file by using d3 library-->
            d3.csv("SO.csv", function(error, experiments) {

        <!--Return the date column from csv and display in the header-->
  var mydate=experiments.filter(function(d) { return d.AS_ON_DATE })[0].value;
        alert(mydate);
        document.getElementById("mydate").innerHTML=mydate;

     <!-- Initially tried to add this code, but didn't work.-->

                  //experiments.forEach(function(d) {
                // d.AS_ON_DATE = parseDate(d.AS_ON_DATE);
                // });
```

Getting undefined in place of the date.This date present in the CSV file (8/5/2016) should be placed in the header.

Comment: What is `d3`? If you are using extra JS libraries, please include in description or tags.

Comment: I have included all the libraries I am using.